# How to improve Django N+1 problem for data export?

Tags: python, sql, django, performance, orm

I am trying to export data as CSV and for that purpose need to query thousands of model instances. Without any optimisations, my code can export ~700 instances and their related statuses. Any more and the server times out with a `502 - Bad Gateway` error.

Adding `prefetch_related('statuses')` improved performance, but it still crashes when selecting more than ~1000 instances.

Statuses 200 and 300 can be missing or exist multiple times. Otherwise I could ditch the line `obj.statuses.filter(status=status_number).first()` and simply append them in order, but I think it is necessary here.

How can I improve performance for this code snippet? Or am I using `prefetch_related()` incorrectly?

```
# models.py
class MyExportModel(models.Model):
    id = models.PrimaryKey()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class StatusModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (100, 'created'),
        (200, 'paid'),
        (300, 'cancelled'),
        (400, 'billed'),
        (500, 'completed')
    ]

    export_model = models.ForeignKey('MyExportModel', related_name='statuses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


# export_as_csv.py
def export_as_csv(writer, queryset):
    # Write headings into CSV
    writer.writerow(['id', 'name'] + [f'{number} - {name}' for (number, name) in StatusModel.STATUS_CHOICES])

    # Iterate over all selected models and their related statuses
    for obj in queryset.prefetch_related('statuses'):
        fields = [obj.id, obj.name]

        # Append date for statuses if known (problematic section)
        for (status_number, _) in StatusModel.STATUS_CHOICES:
            status = obj.statuses.filter(status=status_number).first()
            fields.append(status.created if status is not None else '')

        # Write row for instance
        writer.writerow(fields)
```